# "Operation Not Applicable" Exception

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I'm developing an application in the delphi6.
I've a ClientDataSet (cds), a DataSetProvider (dsp) and a DataSource (ds) that ds's DataSet is cds and cds's ProviderName is 'dsp'.
I add some records to the cds on some specified conditions.
After I set a filter for the cds and set it's Filtered property to True, when I want to close it, it raise an exception by "Operation Not Applicable" message even I clear the Filter property and set the Filtered property to false.
How can I close the ClientDataSet without error?

Comment: What type of dataset are you using?

Comment: I suspect it is the dbx driver that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ONA error comes from midas.dll and I had it quite often until I switched to my own implementation
you could try midas.dll from newer versions of delphi

Comment: that's what I'm talking about. I believe currently v.15 or even v.16 available

Comment: My problem has been solved by using midas.dll v.10. Thank you very much.